# Javascript Function setInterval() works only one time

Tags: javascript, setinterval

Guys!
I wanna ask about Javascript function setInterval().
My problem is that setInterval() works only one time, not repeating.

Here is my HTML Code

```
<button id = 'btun' name = 'btun' onclick = 'changecolor();' class = 'btn btn-success btn-block'>Color Change</button>
```

and Javascript Code

```
function below(t){
  var button = document.getElementById('btun');
  var quadrant = (t*t + 2*t + 1)+"px";
  console.log('ye');
  button.style.marginTop = quadrant;
  document.write(pix);
}
var doBelow = setInterval(below(t++),1);
if(t > 50){
  clearInterval(doBelow);
}
```

I can't find what is wrong.

Comment: What makes you believe `setInterval` is only being called once?

Comment: Nope, I know that `setInterval` repeat the code. But My code didn't. lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setInterval` expects a callback as first argument, but you are calling the actual function.

Call should be like below

```
 setInterval(function() {
      below(t++); }
  ,1);
```

So here you are creating an anonymous callback which will call your  function below. And better put the exit condition `t >= 50` inside `below` function

Comment: Thank you for your help! I missunderstand setInterval() reference.

Comment: Happy to help you. @오현준

Answer (score 4):

The `setInterval` doesn't work even one time. The reason that the function is called once is that you are calling it when trying to use `setInterval`, and the return value from the function (which is `undefined`) is used in the `setInterval` call.

Use a function expression to create an interval that calls `below(t++)`. You would put the code that checks the `t > 50` condition inside the function, otherwise that will also only run once.

```
function below(t){
  var button = document.getElementById('btun');
  var quadrant = (t*t + 2*t + 1)+"px";
  console.log('ye');
  button.style.marginTop = quadrant;
  document.write(pix);
  if(t >= 50){
    clearInterval(doBelow);
  }
}

var doBelow = setInterval(function() { below(t++); },1);
```

Note: Using `document.write` in the interval isn't a good idea. As it runs after the page is completed, it will open a new page to write to which replaces the current page.